# Auto calculate todays date when doc opens and add days to date in another field

Tags: javascript, date, pdf

I am using Adobe XI Standard and have a pdf document with a text field “Today” with a Mouse Up Java script of

```
var f = this.getField("Today");
f.value = util.printd("mmm/d/yyyy", new Date());
```

**Problem 1)**  I want this to automatically update when the document opens instead of when the mouse enters it but I dont know how or where to place the script in the proper place.

I have a text field labeled “text11” formatted to be a date mm/dd/yyyy

I have another text field labeled “21stDay” which I want to calculate 21 days from the date in the “text11” field.

**Problem 2)**  I have not been able to get any script to work.  Can anyone please tell me how to make this work properly and where to exactly place the scripts as I am just a novice at doing this.
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

I believe that there are two potential ways to do this:

1. An OpenAction entry in the Catalog root with an Action dictionary of S(ub)type JavaScript
2. Named JavaScripts seem to be executed when the document is first opened in Acrobat.

For the fomer see table 3.25 in section 3.6.1 and section 8.5 in the PDF v1.7 Reference, and section 3.6.3 for the latter.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing you can do with a Document-level script containing just that single line:

```
this.getField("Today").value = util.printd("mmm/d/yyyy", new Date()) ;
```

If you encounter timing issues (meaning that the field does not get filled reliably, use the PageOpen event of the page on which the document opens. This makes sure that the script is run only when the document is properly loaded.

For the second question, this should work (not I have not verified the code):

```
var now = new Date() ;
var then = new Date() ;
then.setDate(now.getDate+21) ;
this.getField("text11").value = util.printd("mm/dd/yyyy", then) ;
```

Note that the Date object is smart enough to properly convert a date number greater than the date of the end of month.

Comment: I appereciate the help tremendously!!!!   I have two more questions where can I find the location for the open page entry and will it work if the form is secured to only filling in form fields?

Comment: I added the 2nd script but it would not process I got text11 is null error.     Also I need the 21 days to run after I enter the text11 field's date

Comment: The "fieldname is null" error means that a field with that name does not exist, or is not accessible (when you run the code as document-level script).

Comment: I got the open script to work perfect.  I no longer get the null error it was the t in text was capitalized.  The +21 does not work I am getting an invalid format error.  I have checked and all formats were the exact same as script.